# Как после отправки запроса в ЛС боту, получить ответ от него в беседе

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, php-vksdk

Имеется код у бота, написанный на php.

```php
$cmd = mb_strtolower($message, 'utf-8');
$chat_id = $peer_id - 2000000001; // id беседы

if ($data->type == 'message_new') { 
    // Если это новое сообщение то выполняем код указанный в условии
    if($cmd == '!test') {
        if($chat_id < 0) {
            $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Запрос был отправлен в ЛС. Ответ отправлен в ЛС.");
        } else {
            $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Запрос был отправлен в беседе. Ответ отправлен в беседу.");
        }
    }
}
```

Мне теперь нужно, чтобы при написании команды в ЛС боту !test - отправка ответа была с его стороны в мою беседу. Как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: а куда он сейчас оправляет сообщения?

Comment: Ну, если пишу в ЛС ему, то отвечает также в ЛС. В беседе аналогично :)
Но щас нужно, чтобы при запросе в ЛС, отвечал в беседе.

Comment: Так попробуйте передать `$chat_id` вместо `$peer_id`

Comment: if($chat_id < 0) {
            $vk->sendMessage($chat_id, "Запрос был отправлен в ЛС. Ответ отправлен в ЛС.");
        } else {
            $vk->sendMessage($chat_id, "Запрос был отправлен в беседе. Ответ отправлен в беседу.");
        }

Попробовал так, не получилось :(

Comment: У вас очень странно формируется chat_id. Посмотрите в документации к апи, как его узнать.

Comment: Немного не понятен ход работы, можете добавить класс который вызываете через `$vk`